# Can't connect to my WiFi

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

For past 2-3 years, I could work on my laptop from my room seamlessly but from past 2 days I've been facing some problem with network. It detects my WiFi right but when I try to connect , it pops up the troubleshooting message. I tried restarting my router modem, it didn't work. I can connect to it in my hall. But I can't connect in my room where as my cell phone seems to connect WiFi. I'm currently running in windows 7 professional , please help.

Comment: It seems you are having some interferences in your room, such as your neighbor installed a new wifi router. Does the laptop show less signal strength (less bars in wifi symbol)? Your cell phone may use 5 GHz band so it is not affected by the Problem.

Comment: There aren't enough details in this question for anyone to give you any specific help. Please read [ask] and update your question to include details about what you've attempted to resolve this, details about the router and laptop. As it is, there are so many things which could be involved in your issue that no one here could possibly know about.

Answer (score 1):

First, isolate the problem: Test your laptops WiFi elsewhere, preferably the same type of WiFi router or hotspot, to make sure it's not a problem with your laptop.

It's good practice to first check how many WiFi 'competitors' you have and on what channels. You might get a lot better reception by just choosing a channel that is less occupied, or switching to 5 Ghz. instead of 2,4 GHz. The 5 Ghz reach is less far, but in the same room it's faster and stronger.

A common problem with WiFi is that over the years, more and more neighbors set up a WiFi routers and hotspots, maybe even more than one, and that the number of laptops, smart phones etc. that are also transmitting per WiFi on the same frequencies, has rocketed.

You don't mention where you're WiFi router / modem is. A modem / routers usually is a closet, outside the room etc. If so, consider placing it more central to where you are using it. If that's impractical, consider shutting of the WiFi function and instead buy a dedicated WiFi router, place it central and connect it via ethernet wire. Before you buy one, check that it is compatible with your hardware: There are different WiFi sub standards.